# FCC Pre-Certification Testing

Tags: books, fcc, certification, testing, emissions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [FCC and CE Testing / Failure Resolution](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/42610/fcc-and-ce-testing-failure-resolution)

I am looking to do some pre-certification on several boards. I know several members here are quite experienced in this area. I would appreciate resources such as books/articles that talk into practical design and testing of PCBs before sending them to the test house. It would be nice if you could discuss the type of equipment you use to perform this tests, especially if it's relatively low cost and gets the job done.

Comment: This is pretty close to http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/42610/fcc-and-ce-testing-failure-resolution/42612#42612 and recommend a close.  If you find you need a subset or an improvement we can reopen and refer back to the original.  Just tidying up.