# 24V DC Industrial equipment - which IEC standards to comply with

Tags: safety, compliance, iec

I'm trying to design a commercial industrial product/PCB for the first time.
In order to do it "right", I would like to be aware about the most common IEC / IPC standards to comply with. However this is where it starts getting complicated (at least for me).
I read through a couple of websites, SO questions, the IEC website, most of IEC60204  and even a full list of IEC standards by title - all ended up to confuse me more.

1. Is there an overview about the most important IEC/IPC standards a
   product should comply with?
2. If not, what would be the best approach to get an overview as a
   beginner?
3. What are the most important standards (specially
   in regards to product safety) my product must comply with?

**Some data of the product:**

Voltage: 24VDC

Current: ~10A

Applications: PCB with MCU, with some communication ports, high current LED driver, 2x stepper motors, some LED as user interface, no buttons. Fix installed (not movable).

Environment: Industrial, some dust, non explosive, indoor, 10-40degC

*Please let me know in the comments, if more information about the application are necessary.*

Comment: [This question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/231159/electronics-system-standards-compliance-certification-testing-verification?rq=1) might help.